# My favorites and task switcher has vanished after I upgraded to 22.04LTS

Tags: 20.04, gnome, 22.04, lts

I was using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Windows 10 on a dual booted PC. Today, around 2 hours ago, I have upgraded my Ubuntu using the `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` command. Everything worked like a charm and thankfully, I was even able to avoid the Grub 2.06 issue where it fails to detect any other OS that has been installed on that PC. Now that I have logged in on my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, my dock is only showing the application button (screenshot attached) and all of my favorites have been vanished and I can't seem to access them at all. Even to switch between minimize apps, I have to use Alt+Tab key. On my 20.04 LTS, I got the dock by running the following commands:

First,

```
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

Then,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock extend-height false && gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-position BOTTOM && gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock transparency-mode FIXED && gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dash-max-icon-size 49 && gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock unity-backlit-items true
```

[The screenshot mentioned above can be viewed by clicking here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P52bv.jpg)

Comment: Any type of help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may want to `apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager` (extension-manager) and make sure you have the gnome-shell dash-to-dock installed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and still I didn't find a permanent solution but in another post ([Desktop Dock (Gnome Shell) Disappears Except for the "Show Applications" Icon (22.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426576/desktop-dock-gnome-shell-disappears-except-for-the-show-applications-icon-2)) it's suggested to do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> followed by `r` in the dialog to restart GNOME Shell. This saves me from having to log off and on again.